# How to change the page size of the "latestPage" by using setLatestPageSize()?

Tags: vmware, vsphere

```
tfs = vim.TaskFilterSpec()
task_collector = si.RetrieveContent().taskManager.CreateCollectorForTasks(tfs)
len(task_collector.latestPage) #10
```

i created a collector for tasks,but the latestPage length just 10,how can i change the page size by using setLatestPageSize method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the LatestPageSize by modifying the Service's SetCollectorPageSize object. 
For example, here I set my *CollectorPageSize* to *500*, so the service object, updates the eventHistory collector's page size from the default which is 10 I believe. 

Here is my code is in C#, can totally relate to yours,

Initiation:

```
protected ServiceContent _serviceContent;
protected VimPortType _service;
```

While creating the taskManager:

```
ManagedObjectReference taskManager = _serviceContent.taskManager;
ManagedObjectReference task_collector = _service.CreateCollectorForEvents(taskManager , taskFilter);
_service.SetCollectorPageSize(task_collector , 500);
```

I understand this was posted a year ago, but thought it could help someone else sometime since VMware's documentation is really terrible IMHO.